# "Sign in with LinkedIn" and existing user accounts

Tags: security, authentication, linkedin-api

On our website, we have existing users who use username(=email address) and password to authenticate. Now we also want to offer "Sign in with LinkedIn" because we know that a huge fraction of our users is also on LinkedIn. Doing this is technically not too challenging with PHP.

For new registered users via "Sign in with LinkedIn", I would store their LinkedIn ID upon registration, so this is nothing they can manipulate. So when they return, it's an easy decision: Check the LinkedIn ID, if it is known than all is good.

Now comes the tricky question: If an existing user decides to use "Sign in with LinkedIn" for the first time, is it enough to check if we have his email address in our database and then assume that it is him/her? Should we check additional data or...?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

Since email address is unique key and it represent the username, i think you don't need any additional data to check if it is him since his/her password is equivalent to the linkedIn email address.

Comment: Well, how about a person who does not have a LinkedIn profile at all? Does the registration procedure of LinkedIn require that the email address has to be confirmed in order to work for "Sign in with LinkedIn"? If not, somebody could just register a new LinkedIn account and by this pretend to be the user who never had a LinkedIn profile...

Comment: if no linkedIn profile, then email and password must be use to authenticate them, email and password submitted during registration.

Comment: Lekens, I just signed in on stackoverflow with facebook although I never did this before on stackoverflow before. So matching the email address seems to be enough.